# Javascript Fetch internet explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, fetch-api

I made a script using fetch, but it does not work in ie8 +, it works normally in other browsers, but in IE, I have already tried a number of webpack / gulp plugin solutions but without success.

My code:

```js
(() => {
    fetch('/category.json',{
        method: 'GET', 
        headers:{
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        }
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => changeItems(data.data))
        .then(data => sortItems(data))
        .then(data => displayData(data, 'ranking'))
})();
```

Comment: If you search in Google your *exact* question title the first result is a polyfill for activating fetch in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [fetch polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch). You'll also need a [Promise polyfill](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill)

Comment: I tried to use it, but to no avail again I used whatwg-fetch at the webpack entry point and I imported it into my script, did I do something wrong? my code
module.exports ={
    entry: ['whatwg-fetch','./dev/js/main.js'],
    output:{
     path: __dirname + '/public/',
    filename: './bundle.js'
    },import Promise from 'promise-polyfill'; 

// To add to window
if (!window.Promise) {
  window.Promise = Promise;
}

Comment: What's the error you get? Did you install them with npm first?

Comment: Maybe you're not setting `window.Promise` before fetch tries to use it.

Answer (score 0):

To support older browsers, you need to add the `wg-fetch` polyfills.